# Configure Maven Site to pick up dynamic content

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I have some dynamically built html that I would like to include inside my Maven Site.

Static content can be added according to

https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-site-plugin-3.3/faq.html#How_do_I_Integrate_static_XHTML_pages_into_my_Maven_site

I can't work out how to get site to look at dynamic content that is built in the target dir

http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-resource-mojo.html

Can add resources but they don't get detected by Site.

I don't really want to add a phase to commit and push dynamic content to git in order include it inside the site

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503293/how-to-add-a-file-from-my-source-tree-to-maven-site, which uses antrun plugin to copy a resource to a location processed by the site plugin.

Comment: Actually look at site plugin's generatedSiteDirectory option (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html#generatedSiteDirectory .. defaults to ${project.build.directory}/generated-site) for generated context.

Comment: That last one looks the ticket. I couldn't add to src/main/resource as it would entail me checking in the generated docs which I don't want to do. Will give generatedSiteDirectory a go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need antrun etc. you can go by the default which is documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html#Adding_Extra_Resources):

```
+- src/
   +- site/
      +- resources/
         +- css/
         |  +- site.css
         |
         +- images/
            +- pic1.jpg
```

Comment: op: _I can't work out how to get site to look at dynamic content that is built in the target dir_

Answer (score 0):

`mvn site` is a kind of outdated 8 years after your question :-) but for some reason I just tried this out and the answer you were seeking is the following.

Copy the dynamic part of the `site` under `generated-site` e.g. by doing (this copies png files generated earlier in mvn lifecycle):

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-plantnum-generated-images-to-site</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${basedir}/target/generated-site/resources/images">
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/plantuml"
                                         includes="**/*.png"/>
                            </copy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

`mvn site` will automatically include the autogenerated content under `site`. See here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html#generatedSiteDirectory